# Calling functions from one class to another VS calling functions from a class inside a functional component

Tags: react-native

I'm lost on how to interactions between functional components and classes work in React Native, so here's the breakdown:

I have a class that has a function I want to call, like this:

```
class StoreData extends React.Component {
   StoreArray() {
   }
}
const storeData = new StoreData();
export default storeData;
```

I want to call StoreArray inside a functional component that's in a different file such as this:

```
import storeData from 'StoreData';
const EditScreen = () => {

// Call StoreArray 

}
```

It appears it does not work the same as calling from another class which would be as simple as storeData.StoreArray(); so how do I go about doing this?

Answer (score 0):

Judging by the names you've given these components, it looks like StoreData should be a React Context https://reactjs.org/docs/context.html